# ASP.NET OWIN Azure Ad login not working on iPhone (Safari) browser. Fine on other browsers

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, owin

I've built a very (VERY) simple ASP.NET MVC project using the template provided in Visual Studio for an ASP.NET MVC project. I have added Owin authentication via Azure AD for this project, and attempted to run it (without any other changes / customization).

The website logs me in 100% fine in all browsers and devices (e.g. Android phone, windows tablet, windows PC, Chrome, Firefox, Edge) EXCEPT the one device I need the mobile site to work on - Safari on iPhone!!.  When logging in on iPhone, the Microsoft login page shows up, credentials can be put in, then when it attempts to login and brings up the url to load (my page) it just sits there. Forever. It never ends. Never loads. The progress bar just sits there at about 10% with a blank white page.

Here is my start up code:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
            RedirectUri = "http://mypad-prod.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/Home/About"
        });
}
```

It's barely changed from the template provided in Visual Studio. Can anyone help? I"m desperate to get this working on iPhone without having to tell users they have to get Chrome for iPhone (which the site also works in). Here's what I've tried.

- Checked and configured settings on the iPhone (e.g. making sure 'Block all cookies' is turned OFF).
- Tried adding this to web.config

  forms loginUrl="~/Account/SignIn" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies"/
- Tried adding this to globals.asax

  ```
  public void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
  }
  ```

Please help me :(

Comment: It looks like this might be a known issue with iOS 11. Have you seen this thread? https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/issues/120

This works for you on the Safari browser in the web but not on the iPhone?

Comment: Hi there Marilee, I'll take a look at that thread thank you, but to confirm I don't know if this works on the Safari browser on the web, as I operate a Windows PC and Safari hasn't been kept updated for Windows for some time (which I only discovered when I went to do the very test you're suggesting!) So I don't know if it behaves this way on a desktop Safari browser.

Comment: @JamesMatson did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Hi Nalluri, yes I did - at least, for me. My issue was (as you can see in my redirectURI above) I was running my site on a http: endpoint (non HTTPS). I was doing this just for development purposes, but Safari (I believe) has security in place that prevents redirection from a HTTPS address (Azure AD auth) to a HTTP address (my site). This caused the issue I was seeing. The moment I changed my site to HTTPS with a certificate, the issue went away. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Seamless SSO doesn't work in private browsing mode on Firefox and Microsoft Edge browsers. It also doesn't work on Internet Explorer if the browser is running in Enhanced Protected mode.

For SSO implementation , please consider browser consideration doc published [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso-quick-start#browser-considerations)

As per last update , here is supporting browser list and compatibility

**Mozilla Firefox (all platforms)**

Mozilla Firefox doesn't automatically use Kerberos authentication. Each user must manually add the Azure AD URL to their Firefox settings by using the following steps:

- Run Firefox and enter about:config in the address bar. Dismiss any notifications that you see.
- Search for the network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris preference. This preference lists - - Firefox's trusted sites for Kerberos authentication.
- Right-click and select Modify.
  Enter https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com in the field.
- Select OK and then reopen the browser.

**Safari (macOS)**

Ensure that the machine running the macOS is joined to AD. Instructions for AD-joining your macOS device is outside the scope of this article.

**Google Chrome (all platforms)**

If you have overridden the AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist or the AuthServerWhitelist policy settings in your environment, ensure that you add Azure AD's URL (https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com) to them as well.

**Google Chrome (macOS and other non-Windows platforms)**

For Google Chrome on Mac OS and other non-Windows platforms, refer to The Chromium Project Policy List for information on how to whitelist the Azure AD URL for integrated authentication.

The use of third-party Active Directory Group Policy extensions to roll out the Azure AD URL to Firefox and Google Chrome on Mac users is outside the scope of this article.

Hope it helps.